# Remove space between border-image and linear background

Tags: css

Edit : added Codepen

I have a small issue with my css, there us a weird space between border-image and linear background on the top and the left of a button. Could you help me to remove it please? Thank you for your help.

Here is the codepen. The problem is on the button "text". I seems like the problem appears only on certain levels of zoom on Chrome : https://codepen.io/zamehan/pen/ZMXWeg

[image: button]

Here is the associated css, the button has the class .special-button :

```
.special-button{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ececec 0%,#ececec 50%, #ececec 50%,#f1d0c1 50%,#f1d0c1 100%) no-repeat ;
    color:#616060;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-image:  linear-gradient(to right, #ececec 0%,#ececec 50%, #ececec 50%,#f1d0c1 50%,#f1d0c1 100%) 5 !important;
}

.color-button {
    font-family: "Noxa";
    flex: 1 100%;
    margin: 6px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

button {
    color:white;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 11px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 4px 5px;
    background-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    &[data-color="dark"] {
        $color: #616060;
        color: $color !important;
        &[data-selected="true"] {
            color: lighten($color, 10%) !important;
        }
    }
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: share the html code .. as a side note, the boder image is useless since you are using the same gradient

Comment: share `html` code too

Comment: You should give us html code as well or put this in some codepen and give link here

Comment: What browser are you using as I do not get the additional line in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/vjnfcmtu/

Comment: Try removing `  border: 1px solid transparent;`

Comment: hey, try to click inspect on button and look styles:) maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, and found the following article:

https://css-tricks.com/the-backgound-clip-property-and-use-cases/

I set the background-clip property of the element with the linear-gradient to "padding-box" and the line/space went away.